# ¿Como funciona el controlTransfer?

Tags: java, visual-studio, usb

Estoy usando el visual-studio con la dependencia usb4java, que sirve para conectar y transferir datos a dispositivos USB.

Aquí el enlace: http://usb4java.org/

Entonces he conseguido conectar con el dispositivo, pero tengo problemas a la hora de transmitir datos con el método controlTransfer porque no entiendo muy bien como va el setup packet. Aquí el esquema del setup packet.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el código que donde tengo el problema:

```
int transfered = LibUsb.controlTransfer(handle, (byte)(LibUsb.RECIPIENT_DEVICE | LibUsb.REQUEST_TYPE_STANDARD| LibUsb.ENDPOINT_IN),(byte) 0x06, (short) 0, (short) 1, buffer, 50);
    if (transfered < 0) throw new LibUsbException("Control transfer failed", transfered);
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿Alguien sabe como funciona la transmisión de datos por comunicación USB?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que problema???

Comment: Esta abajo la pregunta